# NHibernate 2nd level cache with Prevalence

Tags: winforms, nhibernate, caching

I'm writing a Windows Forms application which needs to store some NHibernate's entities data in a persistent 2nd layer cache. As far as I know, the only 2nd level cache provider which satisfies my app's requirements is Prevalence, but I'm getting an awkward exception when I configure it:

```
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=key
   StackTrace:
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance(String name)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.GetRealObject(StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.ResolveObjectReference(ObjectHolder holder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at Bamboo.Prevalence.Implementation.PendingCommandsEnumerator.NextCommand()
   at Bamboo.Prevalence.Implementation.PendingCommandsEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at Bamboo.Prevalence.PrevalenceEngine.RecoverCommands(CommandLogReader reader, ExceptionDuringRecoveryHandler handler)
   at Bamboo.Prevalence.PrevalenceEngine.RecoverSystem(Type systemType, CommandLogReader reader, ExceptionDuringRecoveryHandler handler)
   at Bamboo.Prevalence.PrevalenceEngine..ctor(Type systemType, String prevalenceBase, BinaryFormatter formatter, ExceptionDuringRecoveryHandler handler)
   at Bamboo.Prevalence.TransparentPrevalenceEngine..ctor(Type systemType, String prevalenceBase, BinaryFormatter formatter, ExceptionDuringRecoveryHandler handler)
   at Bamboo.Prevalence.TransparentPrevalenceEngine..ctor(Type systemType, String prevalenceBase, BinaryFormatter formatter)
   at Bamboo.Prevalence.PrevalenceActivator.CreateTransparentEngine(Type systemType, String prevalenceBase, BinaryFormatter formatter)
   at Bamboo.Prevalence.PrevalenceActivator.CreateTransparentEngine(Type systemType, String prevalenceBase)
   at NHibernate.Caches.Prevalence.PrevalenceCacheProvider.SetupEngine()
   at NHibernate.Caches.Prevalence.PrevalenceCacheProvider.Start(IDictionary`2 properties)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
   at AcessoDados.DB.Configure() in C:\Users\Herberth\MyProject\DataAccess\DB.cs:line 78
```

This is **only** extra code I'm using:

```
configuration.SessionFactory().Caching.Through<NHibernate.Caches.Prevalence.PrevalenceCacheProvider>().PrefixingRegionsWith("MyRegion").WithDefaultExpiration(60);
```

It works fine when I comment out this line (without the cache, of course);

Here's the complete code I'm using:

```
configuration = new Configuration();
var mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.AddMappings(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes());
HbmMapping domainMapping = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
configuration.DataBaseIntegration(c =>
{
    c.Dialect<MySQLDialect>();
    c.ConnectionString = @"Server=localhost;Database=mydb;Uid=root;Pwd=mypwd";
    c.ConnectionString = DBConnectionStrings.Principal;
    c.LogFormattedSql = true;
    c.LogSqlInConsole = true;
    c.IsolationLevel = System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
});
configuration.AddMapping(domainMapping);
configuration.Cache(c => { c.UseQueryCache = true; });
configuration.SessionFactory().Caching.Through<NHibernate.Caches.Prevalence.PrevalenceCacheProvider>().PrefixingRegionsWith("MyRegion").WithDefaultExpiration(60);
SessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
```

All dependencies are in their latest version.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's the rest of the exception?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because the directories `NHibernate.Cache.StandardQueryCache` and `UpdateTimestampsCache` in the executable directory got out of date.

However, that lead to the next issue -- I couldn't install under `Program Files` because NHibernate attempted to create these directories on first run.